# how to remove the lock icon in my gparted from drive

Tags: gparted

no files on my pc can be used, no idea how it happen, please help me to fix it.

[image: check the image i don't know whats happening]

Comment: The lock represents the partition sda1 is mounted (as /), thus cannot be resized etc.  You need to `umount` it, but it's far simpler to boot a 'live' system and do whatever you want from there...

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “no files on my pc can be used”. I wouldn’t dive in and change things with gparted without knowing what the real problem is. Can you boot? What error messages are you getting. Did you take the screenshot using a ‘live’ system? Do backup any important data now before you do something that might destroy it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The picture shows the system partition `/dev/sda1` is mounted. This is probably because Ubuntu is running from this partition. The lock prevents you from trying to shrink or otherwise modify the partition while Ubuntu is running from it. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1168848/edit) and add more information about which files in the PC can't be used. Exactly how you are trying to use them and any error messages you see. Without these information your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)